# Unable to mqtt_client publish inside a class

Tags: python-2.7, oop, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to use Paho MQTT Client and Multiprocessing to send temperature with defined interval. However, publish command is not working inside class. I've checked **self.mqtt_client** inside **scheduler** it has the Client object.

Is there anyone that can address problem for me?

Everything inside class is working except Scheduler.

```
    def scheduler(self, topic, interval):
    if interval != 0:
        while True:
            if topic == "temp":
                print("Temperature published " + interval) #It's working.
                self.mqtt_client.publish(topic, interval , 0 , False) #There is no error/output about this line
                time.sleep(int(interval))
    else:
        pass
```

Class:

```
class Switcher:
config = None
mqtt_client = None
mqtt_connected = False
switches = {}
stages = {}

def __init__(self, config):
    self.config = config
    for switch_cfg in self.config['switches']:
        self.switches[switch_cfg['topic_set']] = Switch(int(switch_cfg['gpio']), switch_cfg['topic_status'], switch_cfg['initial'])

def scheduler(self, topic, interval):
    if interval != 0:
        while True:
            if topic == "temp":
                print("Temperature published " + interval) #It's working.
                self.mqtt_client.publish(topic, interval , 0 , False) #There is no error/output about this line
                time.sleep(int(interval))
    else:
        pass

def mqtt_connect(self):
    if self.mqtt_broker_reachable():
        self.verbose('Connecting to ' + self.config['mqtt_host'] + ':' + self.config['mqtt_port'])
        self.mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(self.config['mqtt_client_id'])
        if 'mqtt_user' in self.config and 'mqtt_password' in self.config:
            self.mqtt_client.username_pw_set(self.config['mqtt_user'], self.config['mqtt_password'])

        self.mqtt_client.on_connect = self.mqtt_on_connect
        self.mqtt_client.on_disconnect = self.mqtt_on_disconnect
        self.mqtt_client.on_message = self.mqtt_on_message

        try:
            self.mqtt_client.connect(self.config['mqtt_host'], int(self.config['mqtt_port']), 10)
            for switch_cfg in self.config['switches']:
                self.mqtt_client.subscribe(switch_cfg['topic_set'], 0)
            self.mqtt_client.loop_forever()
        except:
            self.error(traceback.format_exc())
            self.mqtt_client = None
    else:
        self.error(self.config['mqtt_host'] + ':' + self.config['mqtt_port'] + ' not reachable!')
        
def mqtt_on_connect(self, mqtt_client, userdata, flags, rc):
    self.mqtt_connected = True
    
    for switch_ios in self.config['switches']:
        self.mqtt_client.publish(self.config['station_status'], "available", 0, False)
        self.mqtt_client.publish(switch_ios['topic_status'], self.switches[switch_ios['topic_set']].get_state(), 0, False)

    temp_interval = 1
    temp_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.scheduler, args=("temp",str(temp_interval),))
    temp_process.start()
    
    self.verbose('...mqtt_connected!')
    
def mqtt_broker_reachable(self):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(5)
    try:
        s.connect((self.config['mqtt_host'], int(self.config['mqtt_port'])))
        s.close()
        return True
    except socket.error:
        return False

def start(self):
    self.mqtt_connect()
```

Answer (score 0):

You mqtt_connect function will never return.

`self.mqtt_client.loop_forever()` Will block until `self.mqtt_client.disconnect()` is called.

You should probably be using `self.mqtt_client.loop_start()` which will run the client loop on it's own thread in the background. You can call `self.mqtt_client.loop_stop()` when you want to shut the client down.

Comment: Thanks for your help however, I basically changed loop_forever() into loop_start() but still doesn't work. I want to start client with server.start() and continue to work until code terminated by user.